# Definition of fibration from a compact Kahler manifold to a compact complex curve

Tags: differential-topology, complex-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold and let f be a holomorphic map from $X$ to a compact complex curve $C$. We say that f is a fibration if it is surjective and if its generic fiber is connected.

I wonder if this definition is equivalent to the usual definition of fibration (i.e. with homotopy lifting property)?

Also can you tell me the motivation of this definition?

Comment: No, what you defined is a singular fibration. It fails the usual properties of a fibration. To gain these, you need to delete singular fibers.

Comment: @MoisheCohen is there any reference for that?

Comment: Consider the case when $X$ is a surface. You can arrange for the existence of $f: X\to C$ where $C$ is, say, elliptic curve (or a hyperbolic curve) and $f$ has singular fibers. From this you conclude that for a generic fiber $F$, $\pi_1(F)\to \pi_1(X)$ is not injective. Hence, $f: X\to C$ fails the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of a fibration. I am not sure how much what I said makes sense to you.